# CentOS 7 NAT routing & IPTABLES

Tags: linux, centos, iptables

I have the CentOS instance like NAT for my local net. There are some subnets in my local net. There is a PPTP VPN server inside one. I have to need to publish this server to Internet.

So. My problem is traffic doesn't pass from the `nat/PREROUTING` chain to the `filter/FORWARD` chain.

- `1.1.1.1` is my external IP
- `192.168.10.1` is my internal IP
- `10.0.1.1` is VPN server IP
- `eth0` is external interface
- `eth1` is internal interface

**NAT Rules** (it works. `PKTS` and `BYTES` are changed)

```
-A PREROUTING -d 1.1.1.1/32 -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1723 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.1.1
-A PREROUTING -d 1.1.1.1/32 -i eth0 -p gre -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.1.1
```

**FILTER Rules** (it doesn't work. `PKTS` and `BYTES` aren't changed)

```
-A FORWARD -d 10.0.1.1/32 -i eth0 -o eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1723 -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 10.0.1.1/32 -i eth1 -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 1723 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 10.0.1.1/32 -i eth0 -o eth1 -p gre -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 10.0.1.1/32 -i eth1 -o eth0 -p gre -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Of course, `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1` and I can ping `10.0.1.1` from NAT server.

The `tcpdump` on port 1723 showed actions on external interface only.

I don't have an idea.

`UPD1`. I checked the routing with `ip route get 10.0.1.1 from <src> iif eth0` and I got `RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument`. By the way I had got some answer then I used any `iif` name (`eth0`, `eth1`, `eth2`). I got the valid route ony then didn't use `iif` argument.

`UPD2`. I added `-A FORWARD -d 10.0.1.1/32 -j ACCEPT`rule into `filter/FORWARD` chain as first. But nothing. Pkts and bytes were zero.

Answer (score 0):

- Other rules is very important. And the order of rules is too. So, check the output of the `iptables-save -c` command. Investigate the rules above those, you have created.
- Between the `nat/PREROUTING` and `filter/FORWARD` chains the routing decision is made. Check the routing with `ip route get 10.0.1.1 from <src> iif eth0`. It should return the valid route. If it's something else, paste it into the question.
- Also investigate an output of the `nstat -az` command.
- To pass the pptp through the NAT you need load the modules for conntrack:

  - `nf_conntrack_proto_gre`
  - `nf_nat_proto_gre`
  - `nf_conntrack_pptp`
  - `nf_nat_pptp`
- In the recent kernels you should explicitly enable the conntrack helpers, especially for the pptp. So you need to add the additional rule.

```
iptables -t raw -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1723 -j CT --helper pptp
```

- Other way enable the helper is the sysctl command:

```
sysctl -w net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_helper=1
```

- Other tools to troubleshoot your issue:

  - `conntrack -E` - conntrack events monitoring
  - `tcpdump`
  - `-j NFLOG` and `tcpdump -ni nflog` - allow to capture the packets from the iptables rule.
  - `-j TRACE` target - you can investigate the path of packets through the firewall rules.

**P.S.** Update the question if you're still stuck.